# IE10 in Win RT can not connect server on local network

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, internet-explorer-10

When I browse the web with IE10 in win8's Metro part there is no problem but when I try to view page that is located on server in my local network(the same subnet) it displays this message:

```
This page can't be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://192.168.1.100  is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

If following these suggestions didn't work, resetting your connection might help.

Reset connection [<-a button here]


Get more help with connection problems
```

Now the funny part is that there is an option in metro version of ie10 to open page on desktop (in regular IE10) and than it works with no problem. 
I can't find or think of any security setting that would restrict browsing websites inside your own local network.

(this is Windows 8 32Bit Release Preview build 8400)

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a restriction on opening local sites (as in on your own machine) in Metro. Maybe it is related.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to EPM (Enhanced Protected Mode) in IE10.  It's hard to summarize in an answer here, but Eric Lawrence (a PM on the IE team) has an excellent post detailing everything about EPM:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

In particular, read the "Loopback-blocked" and "Private Network resources" sections.

In your case, you might try one of these approaches:

1. Try aliasing the dotted hostname (`http://192.168.1.100`) via a custom DNS entry (e.g. `http://myservice`)
2. Change the Trusted Zones settings
3. See if your network connection was established as sharing or non-sharing, which would trigger private vs. public mode.

Again, see Eric's post for the details of each of these.